# match and print data into CSV file

Tags: shell, awk, grep, sh

I'm struggling to fetch data from a file having the same format as mentioned below into a new output file(CSV) using shell Script.

```
[+++]          Added Names:          [+++]
     -> Add- abc.txt (732):
     -> Add- bcd.txt (490):
[+++]         Enabled Names:         [+++]
     -> Mod- cde.txt (105):
     -> Mod- efg.txt (105):
[+++]          Deleted Names:          [+++]
     -> Del- fgh.txt (4):
     -> Del- xyz.txt (45):
[+++]      Added non-names lines:     [+++]
     -> Added to test.txt (41):
     -> Added to bgh.txt (41):
        # This distribution may contain names under different licenses.
```

and the expected output should look like

```
Add,abc.txt,732
Add,bcd.txt,490
Mod,cde.txt,105
Mod,efg.txt,105
Del,fgh.txt,4
Del,xyz.txt,45
```

Here Output renames the same as per last.The only thing which is not required is **-> Added to test.txt (41):** and  **-> Added to bgh.txt (41):**.which is part of **[+++]      Added non-names lines:     [+++]**

Answer (score 3):

You can use this `awk` command with a custom input field separator:

```
awk -v OFS=, -F '[->:()[:blank:]]+' 'index($0, "[+++]") {
p=($0 ~ / (Added|Deleted|Enabled) Names:/); next} p && /-> /{print $2, $3, $4}' file

Add,abc.txt,732
Add,bcd.txt,490
Mod,cde.txt,105
Mod,efg.txt,105
Del,fgh.txt,4
Del,xyz.txt,45
```

Comment: here i will end up printing extra data,i mean whenever match(->) will be found.It will simply print that into a CSV file.I was looking for a solution where i can use   **[+++]          Added Names:          [+++]**  or  **[+++]          Deleted Names:          [+++]** .I'm Sorry for late explanation @anubhava

Comment: Isn't this matching with your expected output? Your output is not taking any data from `[+++]` line anyway. If requirement is different then edit your question and show updated output.

Comment: Hi @abubhava i made all required changes in question.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach using `gsub` function:-

```
awk '/->/{gsub(/[->():]/,X);$1=$1;print}' OFS=, file
Add,abc.txt,732
Add,bcd.txt,490
Mod,cde.txt,105
Mod,efg.txt,105
Del,fgh.txt,4
Del,xyz.txt,45
```

Comment: how about `gsub(/[->():]/, "");` for better readability, newbie people may not understand what is `X`,

Answer (score 1):

Another GNU **`awk`** solution:

```
awk -v FPAT='[[:alnum:].]+' '/->/{ print $1,$2,$3 }' OFS=',' file
```

The output:

```
Add,abc.txt,732
Add,bcd.txt,490
Mod,cde.txt,105
Mod,efg.txt,105
Del,fgh.txt,4
Del,xyz.txt,45
```